# Schur Decomposition and $GL_{2}(\mathbb{C})$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, schur-decomposition

Is there an intuitive way to show that any matrix in the general linear group of dimension $2$ of $\mathbb{C}$ has a Schur decomposition? (I'm sure this decomposition is not unique)

Comment: Do you understand what it means to "find the matrix of the transformation with respect to" a certain basis?

Comment: All you need to do is make sure that the first vector in your basis is an eigenvector.